# Работа с Certificate Revocation Lists(CRL)

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Как осуществляется работа с CRL в android?
Я нашёл вот этот класс 
[тыц](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/security/cert/X509CRL.html),
для работы с CRL сертификатами.

Просмотреть список отозванных сертификатов(СОС) я могу:

```
InputStream inStream = null;
try {
    inStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.devca);
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509CRL crl = (X509CRL) cf.generateCRL(inStream);
    Set<X509CRLEntry> clrs = (Set<X509CRLEntry>) crl.getRevokedCertificates();
    for(X509CRLEntry cert : clrs) {
        Log.d("logba", "onClick : data="+cert.getRevocationDate()+" serial="+cert.getSerialNumber()+" extencion="+cert.hasExtensions());
    }
} catch (CertificateException | CRLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (inStream != null) {
        try {
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Суть задачи такая: у меня есть список сертификатов хранящихся в хранилище сертификатов (AndroidCAStore). Мне надо получить СОС(из интернета), сохранить куда-то на устройство и при работе с сертификатами без проблемно знать какой из них отозван, а какой нет.

Как мне, например, его добавить в хранилище сертификатов или куда-нибудь еще? Как это делается с обычными сертификатами? Или же я могу только смотреть в сертификаты и больше ничего?